# Is there any way to assign a default value to a generic parameter in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I define a struct of OptionClosureView.

```
struct OptionClosureView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: (()->Content)? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        if content == nil{
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }else{
            content!()
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't want to assign a value to the property of "content", I mean a default Text view for OptionClosureView. In this case, I just want to declare it as below:

```
OptionClosureView()
```

instead of:

```
OptionClosureView<Text>()
```

or

```
OptionClosureView<Image>()
```

or

....

IMO, I don't care what is "Content" standing for in this case. Is there any way to assign a default value to the generic parameter "Content" in order to allow me to invoke OptionClosureView() directly? Something like:

```
struct OptionClosureView<Content: View = Text>: View {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a convenience `init` that calls the default `init` with `nil` content and let the compiler infer the type by only making this `init` available for a single `Content` type using a generic where clause. The type can be any View type, I've just used `EmptyView` as an example.

```
extension OptionClosureView where Content == EmptyView {
  init() {
    self.init(content: nil)
  }
}

let noContentView = OptionClosureView() // the type of this is OptionClosureView<EmptyView>
let contentView = OptionClosureView { Text("Content") } // OptionClosureView<Text>
```